# Knockout.js "options" binding not updating in my Durandal app

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I'm building a Durandal app, and the view I'm currently working on has two `<select>` boxes. I've got both of them bound to a `ko.observableArray` and their value to another `ko.observable` as follows:

```
<select data-bind="options: dateOptions, optionsText: 'display', value: selectedDate></select>
<select data-bind="options: buyerOptions, optionsText: 'display', value: slectedBuyer"></select>
```

The second one is dependent on the value of the first one, so I'm populating them at different times. For the first, I'm querying my data source during the `activate()` call and then passing the data to a separate method to populate the array the data (in the form of simple JS objects) when the promise returned by the request is resolved:

```
var populateDateOptions = function(dates) {
    $.each(dates, function() {
        dateOptions.push({
            display: dateToString(this.pbDateOpt),
            date: this.pbDateOpt
        });
    });
};
```

That works fine - the `<select>` has values ready for me when the view is rendered. But, after that, I can't get either `<select>` to respond to changes in their respective observable arrays. The next `<select>` is populated in a nearly-identical fashion once a value is selected in the first `<select>`, and I can verify that the `buyerOptions` array is indeed being populated, but the `<select>` doesn't change. I also tried adding a value to the first `<select>` by pushing an object into its array via dev tools and get the same result: the array is updated, but the UI doesn't change.

I've used the "options" binding in several other apps and never had this issue before, but this is my first Durandal app so I'm wondering if maybe there's something I'm missing?

Thanks!

**Update**
I added some more bound elements to the view and none of them are working, so there must be something weird going on with the composer. Not sure where to start looking for an issue (the viewmodel and view are very similar in structure to another pair that is working fine). Any tips?

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet, but I figured it out. Once I realized that the view wasn't being bound correctly, I remembered that I could turn on Durandal's debug mode by setting `system.debug(true)` in main.js. With the debug info turned on, I discovered a couple of errors in my code that helped me fix everything up.

Lesson learned - leave debug mode on when you're in development!

Comment: `leave debug mode on when you're in development!`

Whatever is learned by experience is the best `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reference, this isn't a Durandal issue - this is a Knockout issue.

Also, a way that I have found most efficient to do this is the following the same way you have it -

```
<select data-bind="options: dateOptions, optionsText: 'display', value: selectedDate></select>
<select data-bind="options: buyerOptions, optionsText: 'display', value: selectedBuyer"></select>
```

but in your view model make the buyerOptions dependent directly on the dateOptions like so -

```
var buyerOptions = ko.computed(function () {
    var opts = ko.observableArray();
    if (!selectedDate()) { opts.push(display: '<Select a Date>'); }
    else { opts(getBuyersOptions(selectedDate().id()); }
    return opts;
});
```

This way if your selectedDate observable is empty (one hasn't been selected) then no buyerOptions appear, but if you select a date it will populate it based off some value in selectedDate, like Id.  It will also automatically update whenever a new date is chosen, without you having to explicitly tell it to with JavaScript or w/e

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion. I've got it set up similarly, only I'm using knockout's `.subscribe()` to tie the fetching of `buyerOptions` to a change in the selected date. I like the way yours handles providing a placeholder value if no date is selected, though.

Comment: Just so you know in the future, when you subscribe to an observable or an observableArray explicitly in your code it's a longer way of doing the option I put in there.  By making a computed reliant upon an observable it is 'subscribing' to the observable.

Answer (score 0):

Turning on Durandal's debug mode by setting `system.debug(true)` in main.js helped me discover some code errors that weren't presenting themselves via console warnings. With those resolved, everything bound/worked correctly.

Lesson learned - leave debug mode on when you're in development!